# In bootstrap 3, input search bar does not span full width of the column in IE 9 and below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a Searchform in my Bootstrap 3 website.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<form  action="/" method="get">
    <fieldset class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="searchbar" class="form-control input-lg" value="Search..." />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

In Safari, Chrome, IE10 and Firefox - the form stretches the full width of the col-12, but, in IE9 and IE8 the form only spans about a quarter of the way.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause of this problem is IE make different behavior for `display: table;` css property.

[Display:table in IE 9/8](http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/display-table-ie-9t-836314.html)

You can see the CSS class `input-group` of `<fieldset>`, there is an css property of : `display: table;`.

If you remove this, your problem resolved.

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/203/)

OR

You can use `<div></div>` instead of using `<fieldset></fieldset>` with `form-group` CSS class:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<form  action="/" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="searchbar" class="form-control input-lg" value="Search..." />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[Try with div element](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/204/)